# How can I change the title text color of the action bar when the app is paused?

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

How can I change the title text color of the action bar when the app is paused? As you can see below, these two apps have two different colors for its text; black, and white.

**Edit:** There's very little going on in my `onPause()` function. Can the title be modified programmatically from here?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
  super.onPause();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Place your code in onPause().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitleColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

or you could do this:

```
  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
        int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
            if (title != null) {
                title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
```

More info here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitleColor(int)

Comment: Actually I just realized this must be deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I edit my answer, tell me if works the second solution.